# How to take a data snapshot from a SQL Server database, store it and later compare it to a reference snapshot

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, integration-testing

Following scenario: I'm currently migrating a database to use the SQL Server Hekaton engine (Hekaton is an in memory engine, the entire database is in main memory).

To get the most performance out of this, I will use native compiled stored procedures.

So, a lot of logic that was in C# code, will be moved to stored procedures.

Now I want to write integration tests for those procedures.

What I want to do:

1. start with an empty database (or some predefined state)
2. call some of the procedures
3. verify manually that the database is now in the correct state
4. if step 3 was successful, take a snapshot with all the data in the database

And later, I want to just run the test, take a snapshot, and compare it to the reference snapshot.

I could write a tool that just reads all the data and stores it in a file, but I think some tool (or a library I can use) should already exist, but didn't find anything so far.

Any suggestions (tools or libraries, C# would be preferred) ?

Comment: Why don't use ATTACH/DETACH of database file and simple copy them when needed?

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of your database (e.g. backup and restore as new database). There are various tools out there, for example [Red Gate SQL Data Compare](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/index) or [ApexSQL Data Diff](https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-datadiff.aspx), which can compare the data for you.